# How to distribute Tizen .wgt file to Gear S3

Tags: android, deployment, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, wearables

I developed a Tizen gear application. It is for showing notifications from companion Android app.  I got .wgt file as an executable file. I need to distribute that to the tester. Please let me know the way to do that. I tried using Samsung galaxy apps (http://seller.samsungapps.com). It is asking for master app deep-link(master_app_samsungapps_deeplink). I don't want to upload any master app to play store.

Please help me in this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to register a Companion (Wearable) Gear app, you must meet one of the following three scenarios:

1. There is Deeplink extraction information.
2. The IAP feature is used (billing privilege is used).
3. Remote AppControl API and SAP API are used. (accessory privilege is used).

Go through [this link](https://developer.samsung.com/gear/distribute/how-to-distribute) for more detail. You may also send your queries to seller office through [this link](https://help.content.samsung.com/csseller/ticket/createQuestionTicket.do).